# Bus transport prediction using LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, supervised-learning

I have a dataset that contains information of the ppl who enters the bus in given stop in a day.
The day is divided in 10 minutes gap, resulting in 144 samples per day. The data format is:
(yday, wday, time(1-144, 10 minutes gap), stop, N), where N is the ppl who enters the bus. What I want is predict how much ppl will enter the bus in a given stop (stops go from 1 to 4, I have a different dataset for each stop) in a day based on the last 5 days.
I'm new in ML's world, but I think the model should take the last 5 days (5*144 = 720 samples) to predict one day (144 samples). Am I right?

I checked some guides and tutorials on LSTM but I'm still bit confused about the data preprocessing for LSTM models. The data (in csv) example is given:

[image: Example]

As you can see, every 4 gaps (every 40 minutes) ppl enter the bus, that's because the bus frequency is 40 minutes (10 minutes between stops).
In the guides about LSTM models I read the data's format they use is (timestamp, N) where N is a numeric value (like price to predict) and the timestamp is a date. In my case, the timestamp is defined by yday, wday and time. Should I convert the data so I get only those 2 values (timestamp, N)? Or maybe with 'time' and 'N' values is enough?

Sorry for my english. Don't mind to ask for more and accurate information. Like I said I'm a newbie in ML and I'm so lost. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what sort of library for the LSTM you are using - look at the input format it expects and convert your input to look like that.

That said, you're probably on the right track. If you need (time stamp, N), then you should concert all of the time variables into one time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd recommend is only keeping every fourth stop, since you said yourself that the bus only pick up people once every forty minutes. Thus there is no use to challenging the LSTM to learn that pattern that is constant.

Next, the input to the model depends on the library. If you're using PyTorch for example, the input to an LSTM is of shape (num_of_samples, feature_dim) where feature_dim is a vector of features belonging to that sample. Thus in your case I would probably encode the (wday, yday) and probably one-hot encode the stop and separate the N and put it as the desired output.

For more information you can read [this guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/), or [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-de8aeb26f2ca).